Text summarizer with llama model using promptTemplates
Hello I am working on a college project, it's about note summarizer using Llama 2.
Problem:

Takes too much time to generate a response (more than 2 minutes).

What did I try to solve it:

Initially, I was using the llama 2 models (https://huggingface.co/TheBloke/Llama-2-7B-Chat-GGML) 7.16gb bin file (llama-2-7b-chat.ggmlv3.q8_0.bin), I tried switching to lower version and it affected a bit on time but the output was not precise
Tried to run the code on GPU using accelerate

What I am looking for:

I need to build a web app for text summary using React i want the Python file to generate a summary as fast as possible

Here's My Code:
from langchain.prompts import PromptTemplate
from langchain_community.llms import CTransformers
import gradio as gr

## Function to get response from llama 2 model

def getLLamaresponse(input_text,blog_style):
    print("building")
    ##LLama 2 Model
    llm=CTransformers(model='llama-2-7b-chat.ggmlv3.q8_0.bin',
                        model_type='llama',
                        config={'max_new_tokens':2048,
                                'context_length':4096,
                                'temperature':0.01})
    print("build complete")
    ## Prompt Template
    template="""
        Write a Summary in {blog_style} Format, Using this following Content {input_text}.
        """

    prompt=PromptTemplate(input_variables=["blog_style","input_text"],
                            template=template)
    print("res started")
    ##Generate Response From the LLama 2 Model
    response=llm(prompt.format(blog_style=blog_style,input_text=input_text))
    print(response)
    return response

interface= gr.Interface(
    fn=getLLamaresponse,
    inputs= ['text', 'text'],
    outputs="text"
)

interface.launch()
# getLLamaresponse(input_text,blog_style)

and here the part of my other code that works on GPU
accelerator = Accelerator()

config={'max_new_tokens':2048,
                            'context_length':4096,
                            'temperature':0.01,
                            'gpu_layers':50}

##LLama 2 Model
llm=CTransformers(model='models\llama-2-7b-chat.ggmlv3.q2_K.bin',
                    model_type='llama',
                    gpu_layers=50,
                    config=config)

llm, config = accelerator.prepare(llm, config)

If you need any other information please reply
